# kubuntu 11.10 I need to remove the booting file

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu

I had a windows7 " where I installed kubuntu on using wubi" and my  problem is that I installed a new windows 7 because the last version infected but i forgot to uninstall kubuntu before installing the new windows .So I wasn't able to delete the kubuntu and I just deleted all files and folders manually but the problem there still appear in booting process to choose between win7 and kubuntu . I deleted roughly all files related to windows old for the last windows but i still have the problem tried to install new wubi version and uninstall it thinking that I can sove the problem but nothing happens 
:( so I hope u can help me to not to see kubuntu through booting process again

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall the boot sector (MBR) as grub is still there and active.  There should be a tool in your Windows installer disk, but you will need to seek help from Windows folk not Ubuntu folk for this.  Alternately (and probably better), you can install Kubuntu by booting into the live-DVD and not attempting to install with wubi  This will restore grub with the correct settings after it has installed Kubuntu.  If you want advice about wubi You might look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wubi